# Shell IF not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm new to Shell scripting and I have created the below to run a script and get the output and print a msg based on the output.

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(sh ./myprocess.sh | tail -1)
echo $OUTPUT
if [[$OUTPUT == *"\"process\":\"ACTIVE\""* ]]; then
echo "Process Active"
else
echo "Process Down"
fi
```

The `echo` prints the output but my script fails saying "command not found a line 4"

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will identify this for you. It's generally appreciated if you fix everything that finds **before** asking questions here.

Comment: BTW, `sh ./myprocess.sh` is generally bad practice -- it means you're ignoring `#!/bin/bash` (if that processes starts with it) and forcing the shell that interprets it to be `/bin/sh` (which supports a smaller array of syntax).

Comment: You also might consider using lowercase names for your own variables -- see fourth paragraph of the relevant spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, indicating that all-caps names are used by the OS and that applications are guaranteed to avoid conflicting with POSIX-defined tools if they use names containing lower-case characters for their own variables.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree on you mentioning on the way to call the process. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: If it's executable, just `./myprocess.sh` (and if it's not executable, I'd suggest fixing the permissions so it is).